# Unknown method : selectSingleNode() in Internet explorer 11 || Javascipt

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing, internet-explorer-11

A runtime error is thrown "Automation server can't create object" specifically on Internet explorer v11 and it's failing to get desired functionality as a result. I have attached screenshot while debugging here https://ibb.co/XWwqsRw . Attached code below.

The code is running fine in IE v8.

How to resolve this issue or if any alternative could be done.

Thanks in advance!

```
 function bulk_check()
{ 
  var emptyRows = 0;
  len = document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows.length;
  var rows = document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows;
  msob_dcnlist = "" ;
  msob_fchk= -1 ;
  msob_tchk = 0 ; 
   len = document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows.length;      
    var newDOM = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0"); //Giving error here
    newDOM.async = false;
    newDOM.resolveExternals = false;
    var tempDOM = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0");

 tempDOM.async = false;
    tempDOM.resolveExternals = false;
    for(i = 0;i < len; i++)
      {
        if(document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0]){
          if(document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked ){
            msob_bulk[i]='Y'; 
            if (msob_fchk == -1) {
            msob_fchk = i;      }
            msob_tchk = msob_tchk +1;
            msob_dcnlist = msob_dcnlist + (document.getElementById("TBL_QryRslts").tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[1].innerText  + ':') ;
            }
         
        }
          else if (msob_tchk == 0 ) {
                  alert ( 'Please Select a Record');
                  return false ; } 
        else
          break;
      }
       msob_dcnlist= msob_dcnlist + 'EOPL';
  msob_fchk = msob_fchk;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: It seems that we don't have access to the debugging information you load up in google drive. Besides, we need [a minimal code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test and see how to help. With only the description and the error, we can't locate the issue.

Comment: The code is failing at line 9, giving error "Automation server can't create object". I have attached the block of code and added comment where it's giving error.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot of debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be caused by the specific version 4.0 of Msxml2.DOMDocument is not (properly) installed on the computer your script runs on.

It is recommended to use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0` or `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756987(v=vs.85)). I test with `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` and it can work well in IE 11:

```
var newDOM = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
```